# Cycle index with characters inserted for the symmetric group

Tags: permutations, characters, permutation-cycles

Consider the cycle index of $S_N$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N!} \sum_{g} a_1^{j_1(g)}...a_N^{j_N(g)}
\end{equation}
Consider now the following generalization, where we insert two characters in the cycle index
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N!} \sum_{g} \chi^h(g) \chi^{h'}(g) a_1^{j_1(g)}...a_N^{j_N(g)}
\end{equation}
where $\chi^h(g)$ is a character of $S_N$ in an irreducible representation labelled by a conjugacy class $h$.

Has such objects been studied in group theory (any references would be helpful)? If so, what is being counted?

Comment: Why precisely two characters? Why not arbitrarily many? Or just a single one? Are you thinking of a scalar product?

Comment: The question came up through a physics problem that so happens to involve two character insertion, but indeed I would be interested in understanding what is known about any number of insertions (including one, which may be easier).